# Encrypt some fields of an object using Realm Database

Tags: realm

How can we encrypt only some fields which are sensitive in Realm database? For example, I have an object called Person with fields like name, age, SSN to be stored in Realm Database. I want to encrypt sensitive field like SSN and store it in the Realm Database.

Any ideas how can we do it?

Also, Realm provides the use of Realm-annotations like Primary Key, Required etc which can be used for the fields. Is there a way to create a new annotation for sensitive field and then process those?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088338/field-wise-encryption-in-realm-databasebut Realm directly supports *encrypting the whole Realm*, if you want to encrypt some fields only, you can do it yourself with Bouncycastle (and maybe Jasypt)

Comment: Also answered here: https://forums.realm.io/t/encrypt-only-sensitive-fields-in-realm-database/666/4